# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in line 6

Tags: php, pdo, login

Tengo el siguiente problema creando un login en PDO

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in line 6

Esto corresponde a la siguiente línea

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Este es el codigo:

```
<?php

    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $clave=md5($_POST['clave']);
    $sql="SELECT  id_usuario, nombre, apellido, correo, p.id_perfil, perfil FROM usuario u INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.correo=:correo AND u.clave=:clave";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bindParam(':correo',$correo);
    $stmt->bindParam(':clave',$clave);

    if($stmt->rowCount()>=1){
        session_start();
        $fila=$stmt->fetch();
        $_SESSION['nombre']=$fila['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['apellido']=$fila['apellido'];
        $_SESSION['correo']=$fila['correo'];
        $_SESSION['token']=md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
        header("Location: administrador/index.php");
    }else{
        echo "ERROR los datos no son correctos";
    }

    require_once('../php/Conexion.php');
$conn = Conectar();

?>
```

Y esta es mi conexion a la BD

```
<?php
function Conectar(){
  $conn = null;
  $host = 'localhost';
  $db = 'test';
  $user = 'root';
  $pwd = '';
  try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ':( Error al conectar con la base de datos '.$e;
    exit;
  }
  return $conn;
}
?>
```

Comment: Pon las lineas de tu conexión require_once('../php/Conexion.php');
$conn = Conectar(); al inicio del código, detrás de $correo=$_POST['correo'];

Comment: el detalle es que hay las tenia al inicio pero marcaba error diciendo que no se encontraba el directorio pero hay esta las puse abajo y desaparecio ese error

Comment: y ya lo acomode arriba pero continua marcando el error que comente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es probable que la conexión a la DB esté fallando por otro motivo a parte de un PDOException (y tienes el `error_reporting` en un valor que oculte algunos errores), lo que hará que la función `Conectar()` retorne `null`.

Comment: ahora aparece lo siguiente Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in line 12 ($stmt->execute();)

Comment: Veo que los `bindParam()` los has colocado _después_ del `execute()`, cuando debería ser antes.

Comment: Gracias amigo ya funciona bien ahora tengo una consulta tengo 3 perfiles quiero que al entrar alguien le identifique su perfil y lo mande a su seccion como puedo hacerlo y gracias